# problem with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Here is my code :

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE age= "$age", town = "$town" and ID != "$id"';
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$numResults1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
```

My variables are fine, they have data in them.  The error is this :

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in.....

There is a possibility that numResults could equal 0 but it still should not cause this.

Could it be the != in the first line that is causing it??

Comment: `!=` and `<>` are both valid MySQL not equal operators.

Comment: I don't like that your SO username is an advertisement.

Comment: You can see MySQL errors if you change the second line to `$result1 = mysql_query($sql1) or die( mysql_error() );`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you have a bad SQL query:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE age= "$age", town = "$town" and ID != "$id"';
```

Note the improper `,` after `age = "$age"` in the `WHERE` clause. It should be something like:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE age= '$age' AND town = '$town' and ID != '$id'";
```

Comment: Why should you use single quotes?

Comment: Actually, the quotes don't matter to mysql - it is php that doesn't replace $var with the value when enclosed in single quoted-strings.

Comment: I thought you had to, but I see you don't.

Comment: The problem is not that he's using double quotes in his MySQL (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-syntax.html); the problem is that variables within single quotes are not evaluated by PHP.

Comment: @Mike, ok, I changed the answer, but he still has a bad SQL query. There's a comma `,` in it instead of an `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: Your previous answer was correct and you have now made it incorrect. What was wrong was your statement saying that MySQL doesn't accept double quotes. Now you are misusing quotes and the variables $age, $town and $id will not be evaluated by PHP.

Comment: For example, this is perfectly fine for MySQL: `$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE age= \"$age\" AND town = \"$town\" and ID != \"$id\"";` Of course, it's better to use single quotes instead of `\"`

Comment: @Mike, I see how the last statement could have been misunderstood. I did not intend for it to be taken in that manner. I was trying to say you should use single quotes while using MySQL in PHP.

Comment: @Dirk, but using single quotes in SQL statements is not necessary. You can use single or double quotes. Using single quotes in this case simply improves readability. However, if you make the entire string single quoted, the variables won't be evaluated by PHP. They will remain as string literals.

Answer (score 3):

Your query has a syntax error. Check `$result1` before attempting to use it; print `mysql_error()` when it's `FALSE`. You'll be told what the problem is.

Also, your use of single quotes for the SQL query string means that variable interpolation will not occur... so you are unlikely to ever get rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your single and double quotes mixed up. Make all single quotes double quotes and vice versa.

Try echoing `$sql1` to see what I mean

> There is a possibility that numResults could equal 0 but it still should not cause this.

No. It means you have a problem with your SQL.

Comment: Seriously, you are. `$var = 3; echo '$var';` will echo literally `$var` instead of `3`.

Comment: @Backslap: Why do you say that? (a) Yes, you do; (b) Your code doesn't even check.